# Remove htaccess action to public directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel

How I can disable the rewrite rule to access directories into Laravel public directory, without affecting my Laravel project?

ex: I have (asd) directory into my public Laravel but I can't access

if I remove

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

line and I can access, but this affects my Laravel project.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "access directories"? Are you wanting to get a directory listing? Or are you accessing a particular file in that directory? What is the _expected_ response?

Comment: laravel project
ex:
    public/
        /xpto

if in url i write: mywebsite.com/asd this continue in laravel project but if i acess mywebsite.com/xpto i need enter in my xpto directory

Answer (score 1):

This line is doing exactly what you're asking for (which is to apply the rule on anything except real directories):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

However, you seem to have an issue with your rewriting.

Did you take a look at your access logs within your web server ?

Comment: i havent acess, im sry